# Is there a way to forward a domain name to a specific folder via DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system

I've got two sites (example1.com and example2.com). I'd like to forward example1.com to example2.com/example1. Is there a way of doing this with just DNS? I know I could set up hosting for both domains and then just use a HTTP redirect, but I'd rather just have one hosting account. I'm with NearlyFreeSpeech if that helps.

Comment: I don't think so no.  It is possible that you could do something just with DNS provided your web server supported it, but I don't know of anything that does that.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for Server Fault.

Answer (score 3):

Not with DNS alone because DNS only deals with host names, not paths.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of **many** other questions. You should search before posting.

- [Route DNS for subfolder to different server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94820/dns-route-dns-for-subfolder-to-different-server)
- [Domain pointing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197573/domain-pointing)
- ...

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You need to use a rewrite or redirect to accomplish your goal.

In your Apache VirtualHost config for example1.com:

```
RedirectPermanent example1.com http://example2.com/example1
```